# Named Controller Not Executing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

Hie guys
I am currently learning the basics of angular js and i have a piece of code as below:

```
<div data-ng-app="">
    First Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="fName" ><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="lName" ><br /><br />
    Full Name: {{fName + " " + lName}}
</div>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('app1', []);       
    app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.fName = "John";
        $scope.lName = "McKenzie";
    });

</script>
```

The problem is when i name the app, as follows "data-ng-app='app1' ", the piece of code stops executing and the output is given a Full Name: {{fName + " " + lName}}. This also happens when i try to define a controller.

Without defining a controller or naming the app, the code executes just fine. Can anyone explain what i might possibly be doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: You need to define, which controller you want to use, using ng-controller: `<div data-ng-app="app1" data-ng-controller="ctrl">...`

Comment: "This also happens when i try to define a controller" you should show us how you define a controller, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Numyx thats what i have done, but when i define the controller, the expression won't execute and also when i define the controller just like you have done it does not execute. The expression only works when i dont define anything as shown in my code snippert.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and its working fine.

**HTML**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app1">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    First Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="fName" ><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="lName" ><br /><br />
    Full Name: {{fName + " " + lName}}
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app1', []);       
    app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.fName = "John";
        $scope.lName = "McKenzie";
    });
```